# Change column/row index of node in GridPane

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am using a GridPane as a n by m matrix in which I need to be able to resize horizontal bars.

I have a Circle that I have added to as a child of the GridPane, and I have an action listener which allows me to resize the horizontal bars, and that it working correctly.

I am using

```
int col = GridPane.getColumnIndex(dragAnchor);
```

to get the index that the anchor was in, and then I call:

```
GridPane.setColumnIndex(dragAnchor, newCol);
```

(where newCol is the returned value +/- 1 depending on if I increased or decreased the size).

When I do this the Circle node does not move on the gridPane, the col that is returned is the correct position, too. Is there something else that must be done to move a node that has already been added to a GridPane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working as expected without problem. You may not observing "moving" in your app due to the empty column (cell) of gridpane has 0 width. To debug visually set gridLinesVisible to true and add some row/column constraints. See an example below:

```
@Override
public void start( Stage stage )
{

    GridPane gp = new GridPane();
    Label l = new Label( "before" );
    Button b = new Button( "move" );

    b.setOnAction( ( e ) ->
    {
        int i = GridPane.getColumnIndex( l );
        System.out.println( "i = " + i );
        l.setText( "after" );
        GridPane.setColumnIndex( l, 2 );
    } );

    gp.add( l, 0, 0 );
    gp.add( b, 1, 1 );
    gp.setGridLinesVisible( true );
    gp.getColumnConstraints().addAll( new ColumnConstraints( 70 ), new ColumnConstraints( 70 ), new ColumnConstraints( 70 ) );

    final Scene scene = new Scene( gp, 400, 300 );

    stage.setScene( scene );
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: This was it, after I set row and column constraints to the size in pixels I wanted each cell to be each Rectangle moved as I wanted them to.